# Отображение иконок Listview

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать красивое отображение иконок в ListView? Есть вот такой код:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imageListMain.ImageSize = new Size(16,16);
            imageListMain.TransparentColor = Color.Transparent;
            imageListMain.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
            treeView1.ImageList = imageListMain;
            Icon icon = new Icon("../../icons/hdd.ico");
            imageListMain.Images.Add(icon);
            Icon icon2 = new Icon("../../icons/close.ico");
            imageListMain.Images.Add(icon2);
            Icon icon3 = new Icon("../../icons/open.ico");
            imageListMain.Images.Add(icon3);
        }
```

[image]

Как видите иконки нечеткие, и смотрятся совсем не так как на оригинале. Разрешение иконок 128*128.

Comment: точно не помню, но попробуйте явно указать размеры у Icon, так `new Icon("...", 16, 16);`

Comment: @Stack, не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imageListMain.ImageSize = new Size(16,16);
```

Размер иконки я изменил с 16*16 на 17*17 и отображает иконки как положено.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]